# How to show data from second table that has todays date only

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a left join between 2 tables, tables birds and table Weights.

In my php table it displays fields from table 1 such as id, name, species, bird type, minimum flying weight and maximum flying weight.
In table 2 I show the field weight.

When a weight is entered on another page it has a date stamp, I'm trying to get the table to show only the weight entered on todays date to show, at the moment its showing all that have been entered.

How can I get it to only show the weight relevant to todays date. Heres my mysql query

```
SELECT * FROM birds
LEFT JOIN Weights
ON birds.id = Weights.BirdId 
WHERE FlyingBird = 'Yes' OR Weights.Date = curdate() 
ORDER BY AnimalType, Name
```

Comment: please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query and add a [mre]

Comment: well, you're using an `OR` logic gate, which means only *one* of those conditions needs to be true. Maybe you want an `AND` condition instead?

Comment: When I use the And I get no results displayed?

Comment: Fitting your requirements to fit the results is not a practical way of instructing anything. Do you need both of these conditions to be true? If so, use an `AND`, else use `OR` if you only need one condition to be true. We can't comment on why you get no results until you follow [the guidance given by nbk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70674420/how-to-show-data-from-second-table-that-has-todays-date-only#comment124939128_70674420).

Comment: Please run `SHOW CREATE TABLE birds;` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE Weights;` then post the result [into your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70674420/edit). Include some data sample as well.

Comment: do you know what `LEFT JOIN` does to the table? might as well use `JOIN` only so the SQL should be `SELECT * FROM birds
JOIN Weights
ON birds.id = Weights.BirdId 
WHERE FlyingBird = 'Yes' AND Weights.Date = curdate() 
ORDER BY AnimalType, Name` like how @Martin said. ur logic is not right

Answer (score 0):

Cast the `Date` column to DATE, if it is timestamp the data their I assume is `YYYY-mm-dd HH:ii:ss`, so you should cast it to DATE format first.

See example here;

```
SELECT * FROM birds
LEFT JOIN Weights
ON birds.id = Weights.BirdId 
WHERE FlyingBird = 'Yes' AND CAST(Weights.Date AS DATE) = CAST(NOW() AS DATE)
ORDER BY AnimalType, Name
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM birds
LEFT JOIN Weights
ON birds.id = Weights.BirdId 
WHERE FlyingBird = 'Yes' AND DATE(Weights.Date) = DATE(NOW())
ORDER BY AnimalType, Name
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried it but it didn’t work :-( just shows a blank screen. Do you have an email address and I can send you the whole code as I’ve probably gone wrong somewhere

Comment: Hi if this is mysql change CUREDATE() to NOW() -- check my edit on my original answer.